# Remove file of downloadable product in directory

Tags: magento-1.9, php

in my magento web site i have many Sample of downloadable product. I would like that when i click the red "X" to remove the sample and i save it also the file in the magento directory is deleted

[image]

Do you know how i can procede to do that?

If you can give me some suggestion i can try to do that by my self.

I would like to do that because my Magento directory is full of unused documents.